# How do I set C11 as the standard for compilation under CMake, clang and Visual studio?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, cmake, clang

Does anyone know how to set the C standard to C11 when using Visual studio 2019, CMake and Clang.

Currently, I have this but for some reason clang doesn't recognize it as a flag:

```
if(WIN32) 
    add_definitions("-std=c11 -D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS")
endif(WIN32)
```

instead it compiles it as C++

CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.10.2)
PROJECT(cpu LANGUAGES C VERSION 0.0.1 DESCRIPTION "6502 emulator")

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR "./")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG)
find_package(Curses COMPONENTS)

file(COPY "./headers/cpu.h" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/headers/cpu.h")

include_directories(headers)

file(GLOB CPU_SOURCES "src/cpu.c" "src/logger.c" "src/cartridge.c")
file(GLOB MONITOR_SOURCES "src/ui/[A-Za-z]*.c")


if(WIN32) 
    add_definitions("-std=c11 -D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS")
endif(WIN32)

if(UNIX)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -O0 -std:c11 -Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -DDEBUG")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c11")
    target_link_options(cpu PUBLIC "-D DEBUG")
    target_link_options(monitor PUBLIC "-D DEBUG ")
endif(UNIX)

add_library(cpu STATIC ${CPU_SOURCES})
add_executable(monitor ${MONITOR_SOURCES})



set_target_properties(cpu PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "../headers/cpu.h")

target_link_libraries(monitor cpu)

if(Curses_FOUND)
    include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(monitor ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
else (NOT Curses_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(monitor)
endif(Curses_FOUND)
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting and how you setup your project.

Comment: well, it's not necessarely an error, just a warning but I don't really like it, I get ``ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'``, as well as ``'long long' is incompatible with c++98`` but I set the project up on Linux by making a CMakeLists.txt which I added to the main post

Comment: @visu: Post the error message too.

Comment: `-std:c11`? That's not right.

Comment: according to some SO post it was, and also that was the error message

Comment: @Shawn it doesn't work either way

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that apparantly clang uses the official windows SDK to compile, so I'm pretty sure that that's why I can't use c11.

Source: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/06/13/